# Find and add missing substrings using regex (Python)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have an XML in string format that looks more or less like this:

```
<item>  
    <property 1> value </property 1>
    <property 2> value </property 2>
    <property 3> value </property 3>
</item>

<item>  
    <property 1> value </property 1>
    <property 2> value </property 2>
    <property 3> value </property 3>
    <property 4> value </property 4>
</item>
```

As you can see in this example, the first `item` is missing `property 4`. What I would like to do is to find every `item` that is missing this `property 4` and add it manually.

This is part of a bigger Python script, and I've tried using regex methods re.findall and re.search to find all missing substrings and then using re.sub to add said substring, but I couldn't make it work at all.

Any help would be appreciated :)
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't even bother with a regex solution. Since XML is a non-regular language, a regular expression solution is bound to fail (if not today then tomorrow, as soon as the XML string changes).

Use a proper XML tool and search for the required tag. If it is missing, add it.
You just need to make sure your input string is in a valid XML form (which means a root element and no spaces in tag names).

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

xml_str = '''<root>
                <item>
                    <property_1> value </property_1>
                    <property_2> value </property_2>
                    <property_3> value </property_3>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <property_1> value </property_1>
                    <property_2> value </property_2>
                    <property_3> value </property_3>
                    <property_4> value </property_4>
                </item>
             </root>'''

xml = ET.fromstring(xml_str)
for item in xml.iter('item'):
    prop_4 = item.find('property_4')
    if prop_4 is None:
        prop_4 = ET.Element('property_4')
        prop_4.text = ' value '
        item.append(prop_4)
print(ET.tostring(xml).decode())

#  <root>
#      <item>
#          <property_1> value </property_1>
#          <property_2> value </property_2>
#          <property_3> value </property_3>
#          <property_4> value </property_4>
#      </item>
#      <item>
#          <property_1> value </property_1>
#          <property_2> value </property_2>
#          <property_3> value </property_3>
#          <property_4> value </property_4>
#      </item>
#  </root>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without regex. Use Python [XML](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) libray.

Fisrt load xml from string and then look if each child element has "property4":

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml_str = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
<item>
  <property1> value </property1>
  <property2> value </property2>
  <property3> value </property3>
  <property4> value </property4>
</item>

<item>
  <property1> value </property1>
  <property2> value </property2>
  <property3> value </property3>
</item>
</data>
"""
root = ET.fromstring(xml_str.encode("utf-8"))
for child in root:
    try:
        print(child.find('property4').text)
    except AttributeError:
        print("Property4 is missing")
```

Please note that in order to load xml from string you need valid, and well formated xml.

Answer (score 0):

> What I would like to do is to find every "item" that is missing this "property 4" and add it manually.
>   I've tried using regex methods re.findall and re.search to find all missing substrings and then using re.sub to add said substring, but I couldn't make it work at all.

A fit regex for your string format is `<item(?:(?!<property 4).)*?(?=</item>)` — it essentially matches an `item` from its start up to (not including) its end tag, but only if nowhere in it the `property 4` appears. This can be incorporated in a single [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) call:

```
def repl(m): return m.group(0)+'  <property 4> value </property 4>\n'
xml_str = re.sub('<item(?:(?!<property 4).)*?(?=</item>)', repl, xml_str, 0, re.S)
```